# If I'm creating a date/datetime in a column in Sqlite, do I set it to anything other than 'Text'?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, types

Just getting into SQLite and I understand it does not use datatypes the same way as other languages.
I'm building a database and it has to store date and time quite a lot. And I've read a lot about the date and time functions, etc, but I just want to make sure that in my CREATE script I shouldn't have anything other than

```
BirthDate TEXT
DateTime TEXT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but I think the below excerpt may prove to be useful (taken from http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>     24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

Comment: yeah that does it, thanks :). so it depends what type of date you're storing. I must have missed that paragraph somehow.